# How to change react-native-ui-lib picker default color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using react-native-ui-lib for my react native and expo. I want to change the Picker component pop-up background color. is it possible ?

I've tried to use a custom modal but it doesn't start from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I've figured out how to change the list background using `listProps` and top bar `topBarProps` but I'm still strugling with searchStyle, it's still white.